# Adding constraints for fmincon function in matlab

Tags: matlab, convex-optimization

I want to add some constraints in the fmincon function. I have three parameters such that all the three parameters should have value greater than 0 . How can I implement this using fmincon function in matlab

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maximize function with fminsearch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10410930/maximize-function-with-fminsearch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `lb` parameter of `fmincon` function to some little value, `1.0E-08` for instance.

Comment: Didn't get it just setting lb=0 will do the job. I need the parameter values >0 not only >=0. Could you please elaborate?